# Redirect IP address from any page on the website to a specific page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ip

We want to block an IP address from our site but instead of them getting an error we want to send them to an "under construction" page. I have found code that will redirect them from one page to another but nothing that will redirect them from all pages to a specific page. For example:

```
#Redirect requests from a single IP address
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^10\.20\.30\.45
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /under-construction.html [L]
```

How can we change the last line to include all pages on the website?

I found this on another site and modified it slighty:

```
# permanently redirect specific IP request for single page
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} 10\.20\.30\.45
RewriteRule .* /under-construction.html [R=301,L]
```

Would it work?

What is the difference between REMOTE_ADDR and REMOTE_HOST?
I looked it up and REMOTE ADDR is for the IP so I will use that.

I tried this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} 111\.111\.111\.111
RewriteRule ^ /under-construction [R=301]
</IfModule>
```

I replaced the 111's with my IP address and it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

***UPDATE***

I swapped it and said anything except a specific IP gets redirected unless they go to the under-construction page. It still have full access to the site. Is there something wrong with how the IP is written?

```
#Redirect IP Addresses to Under Construction
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

#url to exclude (the page you are sending them to)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/under-construction$

#ip to block
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^111\.111\.111\.111$

#url to send them to
RewriteRule ^/under-construction [R=301]

</IfModule>
```

Question, I have cleared the cache on the server, we are using CloudFlare, does that mean we need to do this another way?

Comment: Why don't you simply try if it works? Why do you ask us instead? And why don't you simply take a look into the documentation of the tool you use instead of relying on finding snippets on google?

Comment: And yes, that will work. This would even more more simple: `RewriteRule ^ /under-construction.html [R=301`]

Comment: There is always a reason, I didn't have access to the client's FTP at the time. Now I do. I edited the question above and tried your suggestion but it doesn't work using my own IP address.   I have tried it in different browsers (incognito and cleared cache). Any ideas on how to get it to work?

Comment: You always have to test things first using your own development environment. You cannot develop and test using a production site! Especially not if it is not your own! The code is fine. If it does not work for you then either your request comes from another address (you need to check the incoming address on the server, not your local address, easiest is to monitor the http server's access log file for that. And you obviously need to make sure that distributed configuration files (".htaccess") are considered at all and for that location by the http host. Did you make sure that is the case? How?

Comment: You will also have to make sure that you don’t redirect the request for `/under-construction` again, otherwise you’ll have a loop …

Comment: So I switched it up and it is still not working, please look at my update above.

Comment: I thought to try this because the website can tell me what IP I am logged in as and when I added it to the code it still lets me see all the pages so the IP is correct.